# One page menu on scroll with underline sliding links as active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a one page scroll menu with an underline sliding in from left to right when hovering a link. I need help on how to make a link active (meaning the line full) when in specific section such as "About".

Heres a picture that might help to show what I'm talking about (notice the link "Run" being highlighted):
[image]

I've seen many examples of a link being active online but its very confusing cause I haven't found one with my specific problem.

The closest example I found online was this http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/zkrh7/ but i still can't figure out how to fix the underline active.

I have created a js fiddle to show what I have so far:
    https://jsfiddle.net/rsrsrs/36rtdboh/

HTML:

```
<div id="nav_Wrapper_dk">
<nav id="dk_Nav" role="navigation" class="cf">

    <div><a href="#home" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r scroll">Home</a>      </div>
    <div><a href="#about" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r scroll">About us</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link3" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Gallery</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link4" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Find Us</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link5" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Contact</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link6" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Catering</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link7" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Blog</a></div>

</nav>

</div>


<div id="home"></div>

<div id="about"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav_Wrapper_dk {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

#dk_Nav {
    width: 742.6167px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2001;
    background: white;
}

    #dk_Nav div {
        margin-top: 11px;   
    }

    .link_Button {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: .7em;
        color: black;
        line-height: 3.3em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: .2em;
        margin-right: 44.8px;
    }

#dk_Nav div a {
  text-decoration: none
}

    /* LEFT TO RIGHT */
    .sliding-u-l-r {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .sliding-u-l-r:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        height: 3px;
        width: 0;
        background: transparent;
        transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
    }

    .sliding-u-l-r:hover:after {
        width: 100%;
        background: black;
    }


#home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: white;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// Scroll Menu
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top } , 1000);
  });
});
```

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example of what you want :

**Basically on click of menu 2 interactions are happening-**

> 1. The elements scroll smoothly to the given id definite point.(**The scroll is smoother now.**)

```
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
```

> 2. The current menu item gets the active class .

**JS-**

```
$(this).addClass('active').parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
```

**Css-**

```
.sliding-u-l-r.active:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

**Below is the compiled snippet of the above explanations :)**

```js
// Scroll Menu
$(function() {


  $("nav  a").click(function() {
    //**Add class active to current clicked menu item  and remove class active from other menu item**//
    $(this).addClass('active').parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
    //** Smooth scroll Logic **?
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#nav_Wrapper_dk {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#dk_Nav {
  width: 742.6167px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2001;
  background: white;
}

#dk_Nav div {
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.link_Button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: black;
  line-height: 3.3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  margin-right: 44.8px;
}

#dk_Nav div a {
  text-decoration: none
}


/* LEFT TO RIGHT */

.sliding-u-l-r {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sliding-u-l-r:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
}

.sliding-u-l-r:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.sliding-u-l-r.active:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

#home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
}

#about {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav_Wrapper_dk">
  <nav id="dk_Nav" role="navigation" class="cf">

    <div><a href="#home" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r scroll">Home</a></div>
    <div><a href="#about" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r scroll">About us</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link3" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Gallery</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link4" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Find Us</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link5" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Contact</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link6" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Catering</a></div>
    <div><a href="#link7" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Blog</a></div>


  </nav>

</div>


<div id="home"></div>

<div id="about"></div>
```

Comment: When you're on home section and click about (the page scroll down to the about section) but after you scroll manually back up and the active state is still on the about section, how can I fix this Sahil?

Answer (score 1):

make a`.active` class that displays the bar as it looks at the end of the animation.

Toggle it on click between the elements like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.scroll',function(e){
    $('.scroll').removeClass('active');
    $(e.target).addClass('active');
});
```

JSFIDDLE Example

https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/yu530bpf/

Answer (score 1):

Modify your css class like this

```
.sliding-u-l-r:hover:after, .sliding-u-l-r.active:after {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

and your javascript to something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( ".scroll" ).removeClass("active");
    $( this ).addClass("active");
    $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top } , 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You jsfiddle example in this snippet with your requirement. Hope this will help.

```js
// Scroll Menu
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("div a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   
1
    $( "nav" ).find( ".active" ).removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
    $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top } , 1000,'linear');
  });
});
```

```css
#nav_Wrapper_dk {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background: white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}



 #dk_Nav {
  width: 742.6167px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2001;
    background: white;
 }

  #dk_Nav div {
   margin-top: 11px; 
  }

  .link_Button {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   height: 40px;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: .7em;
   color: black;
   line-height: 3.3em;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: .2em;
   margin-right: 44.8px;
  }
    
    #dk_Nav div a {
      text-decoration: none
    }

  /* LEFT TO RIGHT */
  .sliding-u-l-r {
   display: inline-block;
  }

  .sliding-u-l-r:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 3px;
   width: 0;
   background: transparent;
   transition: width .3s ease, background-color .3s ease;
  }


 
  .sliding-u-l-r:hover:after ,.sliding-u-l-r.active:after{
   width: 100%;
   background: black;
  }
    
    
    #home {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1000px;
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    #about {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1000px;
      background: white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav_Wrapper_dk">
 <nav id="dk_Nav" role="navigation" class="cf">

  <div><a href="#home" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r scroll active">Home</a></div>
  <div><a href="#about" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r scroll">About us</a></div>
  <div><a href="#link3" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Gallery</a></div>
  <div><a href="#link4" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Find Us</a></div>
  <div><a href="#link5" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Contact</a></div>
  <div><a href="#link6" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Catering</a></div>
  <div><a href="#link7" class="link_Button sliding-u-l-r">Blog</a></div>

 </nav>

</div>


<div id="home"></div>

<div id="about"></div>
```